# Structure for a Rails Postgres Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So i'm still trying to get to grips with Ruby & Rails and Postgres and i need to run a query but can't quite get my head round how to return the desired results

i have the following

**ORDERS**

the orders have many **#ITEMS** 
// as well as a **TOTAL_PRICE** variable

in the **#ITEMS** is an **ORDERABLE_ID** variable which refers to a **#PRODUCT**

i also have

**USERS**
the users have many **#ORDERS**

I'm trying to run a query that will do the following

Check IF the current USER has an ORDER that contains an ITEM with ORDERABLE_ID == 71 with an ORDER TOTAL_PRICE > 40

```
OrderItem belongs_to :order 
OrderItem belongs_to :orderable 
Order has many :items, class_name "OrderItem"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- a variable `@product` that has the `id = 71`
- a variable `@total_price` that has the value `40`
- a variable/function called `current_user`
- `OrderItem` belongs_to :order
- `OrderItem` belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true
- `Order` belongs_to :user

Then I believe it would be something like:

```
Order.
  joins(:items).
  where(items: {id: OrderItem.where(orderable: @product)}).
  where('total_price > ?', @total_price).
  where(user: current_user).
  any?
```

Comment: OrderItem belongs_to :order // OrderItem belongs_to :orderable // Order has many :items, class_name "OrderItem"